# How to sum values of column in one data frame and add results as a column in another data frame?

Tags: r

An example of my main data frame is something like this:

| Group | Additional Data | Additional Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... |
| 2 | ... | ... |
| 3 | ... | ... |

I have a second data frame that looks like this:

| Name | Group | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| B | 2 | 5 |
| C | 3 | 7 |
| D | 1 | 7 |
| E | 2 | 10 |
| F | 3 | 9 |
| G | 1 | 8 |
| H | 2 | 3 |
| I | 3 | 8 |

My goal and desired output would be the first data frame with an appended column that sums the scores of each member for each respective group, + an additional column that takes the total score per group and adds 5 bonus points (see below):

| Group | Additional Data | Additional Data | Raw Score | Total Score (with bonus) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... | 25 | 30 |
| 2 | ... | ... | 18 | 23 |
| 3 | ... | ... | 24 | 29 |

I'm having trouble finding a way to do a conditional summation and then attaching those values to my original data frame. I think I know how to create a column that adds 5 to the raw score, but I can't get the summed raw data figures in.

Answer (score 1):

```
 merge(df1, aggregate(Score~Group, df2, sum), all.x = TRUE, by = 'Group')
```

Answer (score 0):

First group `df2` and then `summarise` then `left_join`.
I replaced the dots with letters:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(`Raw Score` = sum(Score), 
            `Total Score (with bonus)`= sum(Score)+5
            ) 

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="Group")
```

Output:

```
  Group Additional_Data Additional_Data_1 `Raw Score` `Total Score (with bonus)`
  <dbl> <chr>           <chr>                   <dbl>                      <dbl>
1     1 AA              FF                         25                         30
2     2 BB              EE                         18                         23
3     3 CC              DD                         24                         29
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate what you wanted.

```
library(data.table)

# Replicates your main dataframe
group <- c(1, 2, 3)
additional_data <- c(rep(NA))
additional_data2 <- c(rep(NA))
main <- setDT(data.frame(group, additional_data, additional_data2)) # setDT makes it a data.table and data.frame format

# Replicates your second dataframe
name <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
group <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
score <- c(10, 5, 7, 7, 10, 9, 8, 3, 8)
data <- setDT(data.frame(name, group, score)) 

# Use data.table to create your columns (dplyr might be easier for you)
data[, raw_score := sum(score), by = c("group")]
data[, total_score := raw_score + 5]

# Only takes unique "group" values and removes name and score 
data <- unique(data, by = c("group"))[, c("name", "score") := NULL]

# Final output (merges your second data w/ first data by group)
data_final <- merge(main, data, all.x = TRUE, by = c("group"))
```

Final output:

```
   group additional_data additional_data2 raw_score total_score
1:     1              NA               NA        25          30
2:     2              NA               NA        18          23
3:     3              NA               NA        24          29
```